# Where is msvcrtd.dll?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, msvcrt, wdk

Where can I find `msvcrtd.dll` (the **debug** CRT), corresponding to `\WinDDK\7600.16385.1\lib\Crt\i386\msvcrtd.lib` in the [Windows Driver Kit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg487463)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Seems like it's not distributed](http://kobyk.wordpress.com/2007/07/20/dynamically-linking-with-msvcrtdll-using-visual-c-2005/#comment-14).

Answer (score 2):

Having the same DDK on my system, I cannot find the file , however, you can do it with some tools or programatically:

if you are using a program thats loading that dll, you can use windbg to [display the module info](http://windbg.info/doc/1-common-cmds.html#10_modules) (which should include the path), else you can use one of the [psapi functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683198%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

---

After some poking around, it would seem from [this article](http://code.google.com/p/xchat-wdk/wiki/InfoKK) that there is no longer a public msvcrtd.dll to use with the WDK, it does however give some advice on using alternatives. MSDN also supports the fact that there is no longer a debug CRT, as there only [methods for debugging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff554672%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) involve the debug API and/or WinDBG. However I suspect that the dll might be available from a [checked build of windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff543450%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: @Merhdad: just link to the lib then (with the ddk linker) and let windows sort it out, as you shouldn't be moving around versioned debug files

Comment: @Merhdad: and you know the dll doesn't exists why? it might has some special name to set it apart for drivers, just try linking to it, see if windows moans about a missing dll when the driver loads.

Comment: I know it doesn't exist because I've *already* tried linking to it in the past and received an error that the DLL wasn't found, hence why I'm asking my question in the first place. :\

Comment: Mehrdad: see now that info would have helped in the original question.